# How to check if the radio button is checked in MVC View?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, view, radio-button

I want to check which radio button is checked and change the search box accordingly, so if Date is checked the user gets datepicker and if Buyer is checked he gets regular search box. I'm struggling to get the results from the radio buttons since I cannot use document.getElementById, nor can I access my model in this part of the View for some reason, it only works after the form part. Please help

```
`@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Receipts", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <b> Select Search Option: </b>
        <br />
        @Html.RadioButton("option", "Date_time") <text>Date of purchase(mm/dd/yyyy)</text><br />
        @Html.RadioButton("option", "Buyer", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "checkboxDatepicker" }) <text> Buyer </text><br />
        @*@Html.RadioButton("option", "Store_Name")<text>Store</text>*@<br />

        if (ViewData.GetViewDataInfo("checkboxDatepicker").Equals(true))
        {
            @Html.EditorFor( new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm'/'dd'/'yyyy"), type = "datetime" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date_time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        }
        else
        {
             @Html.TextBox("search")
             <input type = "submit" name = "submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Search" />
        }

    }`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a RadioButton is checked in Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765849/how-to-check-if-a-radiobutton-is-checked-in-razor)

Comment: nope :( @leo_acm94